# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_12" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 455, 30), found shape=(None, 30)

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, artificial-intelligence

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = pd.read_csv('cancer.csv') 

x = dataset.drop(columns = ["diagnosis(1=m, 0=b)"])
y = dataset["diagnosis(1=m, 0=b)"]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, input_shape = x_train.shape, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-4708b71cb33c> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_12" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 455, 30), found shape=(None, 30)
```

Tried making x_train.shape a var and then seting input_shape equal to the var